# Нужно извлечь минуты из определенного периода времени

Tags: java, алгоритм, дата, время

Нужно научить мой `ChequeMaker` считать минуты только в период времени с 9 по 21. Я пишу парковку и там платное время с 9 до 21 и только это время меня интересует,а остальной промежуток программа должна игнорировать

```
public Cheque(Talon talon){

//вот здесь нужно как-то извлечь минуты в нужном периоде


long minutes = Duration.between(talon.getStartingTalon(), 
                                talon.getEndingTalon()).toMinutes();
if(minutes > 30){
     this.summ = minutes * 0.02;
     }
}
```

Comment: В чем возникла проблема? Не можете найти разницу между двумя значениями времени?

Comment: Не понятно в чем вопрос. Если talon.getEndingTalon() возвращает время целиком, то возьмите часы, добавьте if по часам.

Comment: метод Duration.between(talon.getStartingTalon()  берет все время. А мне нужно только периода от 9 до 21

Comment: @NursD ну и что мешает сравнить начальное время с 9, конечное с 21 и сделать соответствующие выводы?

Answer (score 0):

Псевдокод:

```
public int getMinutes(start, end) {
    if (start.hours <= 9) { start = "9:00" }
    if (end.hours. >= 21) { end = "21:00" }
    return (end - start).toMinutes()
}
```

И не забудь сравнивать даты, а то получится, что стоишь неделю, а платишь за полтора часа.